# Show hidden div when it is hovered over

Tags: html, css

I have a a hidden `div` and I would like to display it when it is hovered over using CSS. Unfortunately, no matter what I do, the CSS hover selector does not seem to work. In the chrome developer's tools, I could show the div by forcing the :hover state, but otherwise it does not work.

here is my code

```css
.invisible{
  display: none;
  border: 2px solid red;
}

.invisible:hover{
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="invisible">
Text text text
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An element with `display: none` can not be hovered over as it takes up no space in the document. You can set the element's `opacity` to `0` initially and change the `opacity` to `1` when it is hovered over to make it not visible but still take up space in the document and thus will be able to be hovered over.

```css
.invisible{
  opacity: 0;
  border: 2px solid red;
}

.invisible:hover{
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="invisible">
Text text text
</div>
```

If you want the `div` to appear smoothly, you can use the `transition` property. Since only the `opacity` changes, you can add an opacity transition like this: `transition: opacity 1s`. `1s` is the duration of the transition (one second). You can change it to make the `div` appear slower or faster.

```css
.invisible{
  opacity: 0;
  border: 2px solid red;
  transition: opacity 1s;
}

.invisible:hover{
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="invisible">
Text text text
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

See this fiddle, This might help, what you are trying to achieve.
You can adjust hover area using parent div dimensions.
https://jsfiddle.net/pcwudrmc/37399/

```css
.parent {
  padding: 20px;
}

.parent .child {
  display: none;
  background: red;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}

.parent:hover .child {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
  Hello, World!
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm trying to use css, not scss.

Comment: I have added css in my answer. You can copy it from here.

Comment: I need the div itself to be hidden.

Comment: If you want don't want to create parent div you can use body tag or any other existing parent div.
like this.
https://jsfiddle.net/amitmankotia129/pcwudrmc/37409/

Answer (score 1):

You could use `visibility`:

```css
.content .invisible {
  visibility: hidden;
  border: 2px solid red;
}

.content:hover .invisible {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="invisible">
    <span>Text text text</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Make sure to add a parent div, otherwise it wouldn't work on Chrome 23+.

Comment: I want the div itself to be hidden, not just the text.

Comment: @xyz I have updated my answer. You just need to add another div above it.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.invisible{
  opacity: 0;
  border: 2px solid red;
  transition: all 1s;
}

.invisible:hover{
  opacity: 1;
  transition: all 1.5s;
}
```

```html
<div class="invisible">
Text text text
</div>
```